# DocuSign API returns an exception: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: ssl-certificate, docusignapi

I'm developing a Docusign integration with a sandbox account, in my server I have no certificate because it's just a development environment. The  API works fine there. But when I uploaded the Docusign feature in a test server, which has a certificate, the API returns the following message:

> Caught exception: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in
>   certificate chain

I checked the CA in the Microsoft Trusted Root Certificate Program and it isn't there, so maybe this is the problem. But if that's the case, shouldn't the API have returned a different message? I'm positive the server certificate isn't a self signed one, but is there a way to double check that? What should I do about the server certificate?

Comment: This question is much more about system configuration than it is about programming. As such, you might get a better response to this on [su] or [sf].

Answer (score 0):

You will have to get the DocuSign certificate installed on your test server.
You can find all of DocuSign certificates here - https://www.docusign.com/trust/compliance/public-certificates